# Can I create a custom desktop icon for a shortcut in ClickOnce Deployment?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, clickonce, shortcut-file

My application creates a shortcut on the user's desktop with a standard icon. How can I change the icon to something custom? I'm using VS2008 with .NET 3.5. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This forum post explains the various hoops you will have to jump through to get this to work.  I know one of the developers at my work had issues with getting it to work he said he'd found the msdn forum post which helped him out.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/f00e1051-f3ef-46e1-b034-e82f14dc1444

hth

Pete

Comment: Thank you, yes! This is the answer. You must go to My Project -> Application tab -> Then you will be able to select an icon. Thanks again!